# How seo implemented for distancebetween.com website?

Tags: seo, google-search

When I Search for **distance between bangalore to mumbai** in Google, distancebetween.com comes up in the search results. I mean if I search for distance between any source to destination they have results for that. They have one dynamic page where user can enter source and destination and those inputs will be passed to google maps api to get the distance.
 How did they do SEO for their website?

Here is the **Sample URL:**

http://www.distancesbetween.com/distance-between/distance-from-mumbai-to-andhra-pradesh-office-of-the-jds/86843/r3/

1. Are they generating all source to destination URLs and stored in any html file which will used by the Google crawler?
2. Are they storing all the source to destination in sitemap.xml ?If at all storing the combination could be in millions right?

Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: There are many deep links to pre-calculated pages under the `more` sections of `Most Popular Searches` on their homepage.

Comment: Thanks Rob, you are absolutely correct, i have found many links under popular searches, more categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would take a look at the Google results for a search query site:distancesbetween.com you would see 654000 results, which basically means that most of the links generated are indexed by Google. As Rob already mentioned, you can find links to the popular searches on the website and each link can be crawled by Google-bots. 
So to answer your questions:

1. Yes
2. Couldn't find their sitemap.xml, so pretty sure No, they are not.